# Express default route parameter

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am surprised I can't find this so it has probably been answered before (and I'm searching for the wrong thing).

Basically, is it possible and how do I set a default value on a nodejs express route?

```
// Test route
router.route('/tests/:id')
    .get(testsController.tests.get);
```

Where if `:id` is not set, it will automatically set to an arbitrary value, e.g. 1.

Controller Code:

```
var testsController = {
    tests: {
        get: function (req, res, next) {
            if (req.params.id) {
                res.render('tests.html', { title: 'The Site', id: req.params.id });
                next();
            } else {
                //res.redirect('/')
                console.log('here');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I know in PHP Symfony2 I can do something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/tests/{id}")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function testAction(Request $request, $id=1)
{
}
```

Comment: This probably can help you http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are setting it up correctly, but you need to get the parameter afterwards from the request object, it is not passed automatically to the action:

```
req.params.id
```

**[Edit]**
To make the parameter optional you should define the route like this:

```
router.route('/tests/:id?')
    .get(testsController.tests.get);
```

and if you want to set a default value do that:

```
res.render('tests.html', { title: 'The Site', id: req.params.id || 1 });
```

Comment: ah yes, this makes sense, I realise what is going on now (I have a controller file too which I didn't paste the code for, will add to my question now). So basically because there is an if statement, it doesn't matter if it isn't set because you can set it there and then right?

Comment: I expanded the answer, I hope it's what you need